# Why the compiler looks for dependencies packages on src folder instead of node_modules folder in a React app running on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, material-ui, modulenotfounderror

I am working with React and Material UI on a Windows 10 and everything works fine but when I open the project on Ubuntu I get this error for many imports:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'name of the imported package in '/home/computerName/Desktop/Dev/nameOfTheProject/client/src
```

For example:

```
import WalletConnectProvider from '@walletconnect/web3-provider';
```

error:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '@walletconnect/web3-provider' in '/home/computerName/Desktop/Dev/nameOfTheProject/client/src
```

And so on for every Material UI import and other dependencies.

Ubuntu is looking for the dependencies packages inside the src folder instead of the node_modules folder.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an the answer for this problem.
Since Ubuntu is case-sensitive and since the Material UI name folders in node_modules are capitalized I was getting this error because I was importing some Material UI dependencies with lowercase, like this:

```
import Card from '@material-ui/core/card';
```

Where card dependencies in node_modules folder is capitalized Card.
While Windows ignores this and does not throw an error, Ubuntu does because is set to be case-sensitive.

So I had to change all the lowercase dependencies into capitalized.

Another solution would be to import the destructured dependencies:

```
import {Card} from '@material-ui/core';
```